# Как программно сделать флажок CheckBox true в Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, checkbox, android-navigation-drawer, settings

Как программно сделать флажок CheckBox true в Navigation Drawer? именно программно то есть при запуске будет флажок, реализовать нужно не через XML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине это не NavigationDrawer, а попап-меню экшенбара.  NavigationDrawer это то, что выезжает сбоку и переключает экраны в приложении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привожу свой пример. Это разметка данного элемента в xml.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menuCheck"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="check"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Меню не является View, именно поэтому нельзя делать findViewById, чтобы найти в меню элемент и поставить в нем флажок.
Для того, чтобы поставить флажок программно, необходимо в Activity переопределить метод onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.menuCheck).setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }
```